# Calculating the cumulative product of a matrix error, setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

```
matrix = np.matrix([[1, 0.01], [2, 0.003], [3, 0.015], [4, 0.026], [5, 0.006]])
cumulative = np.zeros(5)
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    p = 1
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        p = p*(1 + matrix[1][j])
    p = p-1
    cumulative[i] = p
print(cumulative)
```

I get a value error when I run this code:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What output did you expect to get from the code? `matrix[1][j]` is an array here, so `p` becomes an array.

Comment: @Sol You might find it easier to work with `np.array` rather than `np.matrix`. `matrix[1][j]` would give you an entry if `matrix` were a numpy array but, as Martijn notes, does not do so for a numpy matrix

Comment: I've made a guess as to what your expected output would be and added advice on how to produce that to my answer. Your question would be much better received if you included that information in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `matrix[1][j]` is an array, not a single value. Matrixes try to maintain their 2D nature, so indexing with a single value gives you another matrix.

You need to use a tuple index to get individual values:

```
p = p * (1 + matrix[1, j])
```

Note the comma!

Demo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.matrix([[1, 0.01], [2, 0.003], [3, 0.015], [4, 0.026], [5, 0.006]])
>>> cumulative = np.zeros(5)
>>> for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
...     p = 1
...     for j in range(0, i+1):
...         p = p*(1 + matrix[1, j])
...     p = p-1
...     cumulative[i] = p
...
>>> print(cumulative)
[2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Note that *only the first column of the first and second rows* (with the values `1, 0.01` and `2, 0.003`) are being used in your code, each having a length of 1. The *contained* matrix has a shape of `(1, 2)`:

```
>>> matrix[0]
matrix([[1.  , 0.01]])
>>> matrix[1]
matrix([[2.   , 0.003]])
>>> len(matrix[0])
1
>>> matrix[0].shape
(1, 2)
```

You are not processing the matrix per column (so across all 5 rows), and `len(matrix[0])` is never going to give you 2 or 5.

You may want to use [`matrix.getA()`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.getA.html) to get a numpy array for a given matrix column, and then just use [`numpy.ndarray.cumprod()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumprod.html) to calculate the cumulative product. Add 1 to all values in the column, then subtract 1 again afterwards:

```
cumulative =  (1 + matrix[:, 1].getA()).cumprod() - 1
```

Here, `[:, 1]` takes the second column (the values `0.01`, `0.003`, `0.015`, etc.), turns that into an array (unwrapping the matrix), adds 1 to each value and calculates their cumulative product (5 values again). We then subtract 1 from each of those 5 values.

This produces:

```
>>> cumulative = (1 + matrix[:, 1].getA()).cumprod() - 1
>>> print(cumulative)
[0.01       0.01303    0.02822545 0.05495931 0.06128907]
```

Comment: It works. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make this code work, such as changing "i+1" on line 6 to "i-1", but that's not necessarily what you need. I hope you can clarify your purpose so that we can give the correct solution.

If you want to think by yourself, the following knowledge is what I think you need:

1. The shape of this matrix is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix.shape
   (5, 2)
   ```
2. The number of this matrix's rows is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix.shape[0]
   5
   ```
3. The number of this matrix's columns is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix.shape[1]
   2
   ```
4. The first column of the matrix is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix[:, 0]
   matrix([[1.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [4.],
       [5.]])
   ```
5. The first row of the matrix is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix[0]
   matrix([[1.  , 0.01]])
   ```
6. The first row and first column element of the matrix is:

   ```py
   >>> matrix[0, 0]
   1.0
   ```

Comment: Yes, we already pointed this out in comments on the question. Changing `i + 1` to `i - 1` would not fix the problem. It only will result in *no multiplication at all* because the range is then from `0` to `2` (non-inclusive) to `0` to `0`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters indeed so. Didn't see your comments on it when I opened the question, presumably they were posted while I was trying to experiment.

Comment: My comments were posted 30 minutes and 10 minutes before your answer was posted, respectively. If a question is unclear, it may be better to move to one that is better worded and has all the information already there.

Comment: It just means that I spend a super lot of time experimenting and expressing :|